# What development tools are there for the IBMi (AS/400, iSeries)?

Tags: ibm-midrange

Are there any development tools for the IBMi - also known as the AS/400, iSeries?

Comment: There's CL, RPG IV, COBOL, C compiler...why do you ask? the AS/400 is a mainframe system....

Comment: Actually the AS/400 is a midrange system, not a mainframe.

Comment: Which is mostly capable of anything the IBM mainframe does ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the native stuff (the "green-screen" tools). Most of them are also available as client-server (aka GUI interface) too.

You can use a popular alternative as LANSA (www.lansa.com).

Or you can use Java!!!. The iSeries is a hell of Java machine. Everything for your new world impressing application is already on board (JVM, JDK, class libraries (JtOpen) to access the local iSeries stuff). And last, but not least, the world-class database manager DB2 is native in the OS. How about that!?

(and no, I'm not a IBM representative. Just a happy RPG coder ;-)

Comment: Just notice that the CPU is slow, so you should stick to I/O bound work in Java.  Also a separate memory pool is nice.

Comment: The java programmer can work like he/she is used to do. The iSeries system manager has to learn a new couple of tricks. For a starter, he has to activate the correct (aka optimized) java virtual machine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.  The current Windows-based IDE is called "Rational Developer for i" and you can find more information at http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/developer/rdi/.  The green-screen tools are PDM, SEU, SDA, etc.

Also there is a relatively new non-IBM solution called [RPG Next Gen (http://www.rpgnextgen.com/)](http://www.rpgnextgen.com/).

Answer (score 2):

A free alternative the RDi is the RPG Next Gen editor.

http://rpgnextgen.sourceforge.net/

Be warned, it does not support the maintenance of the line level source dates.

Answer (score 2):

Use iRPGEditor- It's Open Source Editor write in Java.
Actually is in versión 1.0b1
https://github.com/egomezal/iRPGEditor

Answer (score 1):

If you'd really like a niche career, I'd also recommend Delphi for the AS/400:

http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-400

Comment: Do you have experience with it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I think m-Power should be mentioned. m-Power (and its predecessors) is one of the most well established development tools available for the iSeries, dating back to the IBM System/38 (in the early 80s), which was later replaced by the AS/400. Here's the website: http://www.mrc-productivity.com/

Answer (score 0):

MiWorkplace, MiW, could replace SEU, not RDi. It improves the user experience of SEU users whose management will not pay the price of RDi. For a review by Jon Paris see this [link](https://www.itjungle.com/2017/03/13/guru-miworkplace-alternative-seu/).